# is it possible to add UILabel inside Tab Bar Item (BadgeValue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, badge

[image: The Tab bar controller with 5 tabs]

Referring above image:
1. The issue is to set Number inside circle of Tasks image in "Tasks tab".
2. Is it possible to set number i.e UILabel at given location inside tab bar item?

Thank You.

Updated:
This is what i wanted and got using badge value:
[image]

[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items]
          objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:10 ]];

To get badge value to application value:

[image]

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That design element is called a 'badge'. You set a tab bar item's badge by setting its `badgeValue` property to a suitable number.

Check the docs for `UITabBarItem` for more information on the `badgeValue` property.

Comment: Note that the `badgeValue` property on the `UITabBarItem` is actually an `NSString`.